# Get average product attribute value rating outside loop (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, while-loop, rating

Below code outputs the average ratings (via shortcode) of all products within the loop like this: 3.0 4.0 4.0 5.0

```
function iw_get_product_ratings_by_attribute_shortcode() {

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation'=>'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_merk',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'twins'
            )
        )
    ) );

        // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $rating = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '_wc_average_rating', true );

            if ($rating != 0) { echo number_format((float)$rating, 1, '.', ''); }

        }

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

}

add_shortcode('iw_get_product_ratings_by_attribute', 'iw_get_product_ratings_by_attribute_shortcode');
```

How can I get the OVERALL AVERAGE of these numbers?

**In other words: I would like to display the average rating of all products (with attribute 'pa_merk' and value 'twins')**

**UPDATE: BELOW CODE DOES THE JOB :)**

```
function iw_get_product_ratings_by_attribute_shortcode() {

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation'=>'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_merk',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'twins'
            )
        )
    ) );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $ratingSum = 0;
        $postsCount = 0;

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $rating = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '_wc_average_rating', true );

            if ($rating != 0) {
                $postsCount++;
                $ratingSum += $rating;
            }

        }

        if ($ratingSum > 0 && $postsCount > 0) {
           return $ratingSum / $postsCount; // todo do the rounding stuff 
        }

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}

add_shortcode('iw_get_product_ratings_by_attribute', 'iw_get_product_ratings_by_attribute_shortcode');
```

Comment: You add them in the loop and and outside of the loop you divide the sum by the amount of loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (can't test it now, might have syntax errors, and can probably be improved. feel free to edit my answer!)

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $ratingSum = 0;
    $postsCount = 0;

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $postsCount++;

        $rating = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '_wc_average_rating', true );

        $ratingSum += $rating;

        if ($rating != 0) { echo number_format((float)$rating, 1, '.', ''); }

    }

    if ($ratingSum > 0 && $postsCount > 0) {
       echo $ratingSum / $postsCount; // todo do the rounding stuff 
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Possibly, you can get $post_count or $found_posts from $query - saves you the counting.

Comment: I don't get any errors only the output is incorrect :) I have a 5 and a 1 star rating so the output needs to be 3 but instead it gives me: 0.31578947368421 ?? lol.

Comment: Oh lol I noticed that al products (even the ones without a rating) were calculated so I just added: if ($rating != 0) {....} and everything works great. Many thank Jasie. I have updated my question with the working code.

Comment: True, good finding. But please: edit MY answer, not YOUR question.

Comment: Done and tnx again.